# Returning array of JSON objects from related fields in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, json, aggregate

I have the following schema and some data inserted into the DB.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v14)**

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    is_active BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    is_staff BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    is_superuser BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
);
INSERT INTO users 
                (id, email, password, first_name, last_name, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser) 
            VALUES (1, 'sir@a.com', '23456ses', 'John', 'Idogun', true, true, true);
INSERT INTO users 
                (id, email, password, first_name, last_name, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser) 
            VALUES (2, 'ma@a.com', '23456ses', 'Nelson', 'Idogun', true, true, true);
-- articles table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    fore_image TEXT NULL,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    slug TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    is_published BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
INSERT INTO articles (id, title, slug, content, is_published, user_id) VALUES (1, 'Upgrading from v0.4 to v0.5 of rust rocket', 'Upgrading from v0.4 to v0.5 of rust rocket', 'Upgrading from v0.4 to v0.5 of rust rocket', true, 1);
INSERT INTO articles (id, title, slug, content, is_published, user_id) VALUES (2, 'Upgrading from v0.3 to v0.4 of rust rocket', 'Upgrading from v0.3 to v0.4 of rust rocket', 'Upgrading from v0.3 to v0.4 of rust rocket', true, 1);
INSERT INTO articles (id, title, slug, content, is_published, user_id) VALUES (3, 'Upgrading from v0.2 to v0.3 of rust rocket', 'Upgrading from v0.2 to v0.3 of rust rocket', 'Upgrading from v0.2 to v0.3 of rust rocket', true, 2);
-- Tags table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tags(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    description TEXT NULL
);
INSERT INTO tags (id, name, description)
    VALUES (1, 'dev', 'Internet dev...'), (2,
            'rust',
            'Confident and safe systems language.'
        ),(3,
            'python',
            'import this. Beautiful is better than ugly...'
        );
-- articles and tags table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles_tags(
    article_id INT NOT NULL references articles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    tag_id INT NOT NULL references tags(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (article_id, tag_id)
);

INSERT INTO articles_tags(article_id, tag_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 3);
```

---

I also have this query to get a tag and then output all articles having that tag in a list of objects. Each article should in turn have its respective authors. The query did output that but what I want is slightly different.

**Query and Current Result**

```
SELECT
    t.id AS t_id,
    t.name AS t_name,
    t.description AS t_description,
    json_agg(
    jsonb_build_object(
        'id', a.id,
        'fore_image', a.fore_image,
        'title', a.title,
        'slug', a.slug,
        'content', a.content,
        'is_published', a.is_published,
        'created_at', a.created_at,
        'updated_at', a.updated_at, 
        'author', jsonb_build_object(
          'id', u.id,
          'email', u.email,
          'first_name', u.first_name,
          'last_name', u.last_name,
          'is_active', u.is_active,
          'is_staff', u.is_staff,
          'is_superuser', u.is_superuser
        )
    )) AS articles
FROM tags AS t
JOIN articles_tags AS a_t ON a_t.tag_id = t.id
JOIN articles AS a ON a_t.article_id = a.id
JOIN users AS u ON a.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY t.id, a.id
HAVING t.id = 1;
```

| t_id | t_name | t_description | articles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dev | Internet dev... | [{"id":1,"slug":"Upgrading from v0.4 to v0.5 of rust rocket","title":"Upgrading from v0.4 to v0.5 of rust rocket","author":{"id":1,"email":"sir@a.com","is_staff":true,"is_active":true,"last_name":"Idogun","first_name":"John","is_superuser":true},"content":"Upgrading from v0.4 to v0.5 of rust rocket","created_at":"2023-02-11T08:07:56.098667+00:00","fore_image":null,"updated_at":"2023-02-11T08:07:56.098667+00:00","is_published":true}] |
| 1 | dev | Internet dev... | [{"id":2,"slug":"Upgrading from v0.3 to v0.4 of rust rocket","title":"Upgrading from v0.3 to v0.4 of rust rocket","author":{"id":1,"email":"sir@a.com","is_staff":true,"is_active":true,"last_name":"Idogun","first_name":"John","is_superuser":true},"content":"Upgrading from v0.3 to v0.4 of rust rocket","created_at":"2023-02-11T08:07:56.10037+00:00","fore_image":null,"updated_at":"2023-02-11T08:07:56.10037+00:00","is_published":true}] |
| 1 | dev | Internet dev... | [{"id":3,"slug":"Upgrading from v0.2 to v0.3 of rust rocket","title":"Upgrading from v0.2 to v0.3 of rust rocket","author":{"id":2,"email":"ma@a.com","is_staff":true,"is_active":true,"last_name":"Idogun","first_name":"Nelson","is_superuser":true},"content":"Upgrading from v0.2 to v0.3 of rust rocket","created_at":"2023-02-11T08:07:56.100741+00:00","fore_image":null,"updated_at":"2023-02-11T08:07:56.100741+00:00","is_published":true}] |

---

**Expected result**

| t_id | t_name | t_description | articles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dev | Internet dev... | [{"id":1,"slug":"Upgrading from v0.4 to v0.5 of rust rocket","title":"Upgrading from v0.4 to v0.5 of rust rocket","author":{"id":1,"email":"sir@a.com","is_staff":true,"is_active":true,"last_name":"Idogun","first_name":"John","is_superuser":true},"content":"Upgrading from v0.4 to v0.5 of rust rocket","created_at":"2023-02-11T08:07:56.098667+00:00","fore_image":null,"updated_at":"2023-02-11T08:07:56.098667+00:00","is_published":true}, {"id":2,"slug":"Upgrading from v0.3 to v0.4 of rust rocket","title":"Upgrading from v0.3 to v0.4 of rust rocket","author":{"id":1,"email":"sir@a.com","is_staff":true,"is_active":true,"last_name":"Idogun","first_name":"John","is_superuser":true},"content":"Upgrading from v0.3 to v0.4 of rust rocket","created_at":"2023-02-11T08:07:56.10037+00:00","fore_image":null,"updated_at":"2023-02-11T08:07:56.10037+00:00","is_published":true}, {"id":3,"slug":"Upgrading from v0.2 to v0.3 of rust rocket","title":"Upgrading from v0.2 to v0.3 of rust rocket","author":{"id":2,"email":"ma@a.com","is_staff":true,"is_active":true,"last_name":"Idogun","first_name":"Nelson","is_superuser":true},"content":"Upgrading from v0.2 to v0.3 of rust rocket","created_at":"2023-02-11T08:07:56.100741+00:00","fore_image":null,"updated_at":"2023-02-11T08:07:56.100741+00:00","is_published":true}] |

### **How can I achieve this result with optimal performance? Any modification to the query?**

[View on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c3b94/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems no need to group by `a.id`. And that `HAVING` should probably be a `WHERE`, although that itself won't make a difference to the results, only the performance.

So simply change this

```
GROUP BY t.id, a.id
HAVING t.id = 1;
```

to this:

```
WHERE t.Id = 1
GROUP BY t.id;
```