# How to use LIMIT and OFFSET in Postgres' json_agg() function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, aggregate

With reference to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/323387/returning-array-of-json-objects-from-related-fields-in-postgresql) and [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c3b94/1), I currently have a working SQL query, based off of [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/323421/268838), that gets a tag from the database and aggregates all articles having such a tag. The current query is:

```
SELECT
    t.id AS t_id,
    t.name AS t_name,
    t.description AS t_description,
    json_agg(
    jsonb_build_object(
        'id', a.id,
        'fore_image', a.fore_image,
        'title', a.title,
        'slug', a.slug,
        'content', a.content,
        'is_published', a.is_published,
        'created_at', a.created_at,
        'updated_at', a.updated_at, 
        'author', jsonb_build_object(
          'id', u.id,
          'email', u.email,
          'first_name', u.first_name,
          'last_name', u.last_name,
          'is_active', u.is_active,
          'is_staff', u.is_staff,
          'is_superuser', u.is_superuser
        )
    )) AS articles
FROM tags AS t
JOIN articles_tags AS a_t ON a_t.tag_id = t.id
JOIN articles AS a ON a_t.article_id = a.id
JOIN users AS u ON a.user_id = u.id
WHERE t.Id = 3
GROUP BY t.id;
```

But at present, `json_agg()` is fetching all related articles at once which will be inefficient in the long run. Is there a way I can introduce `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to `json_agg()` so I can control the number of articles a query produces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate in a **`LATERAL`** subquery, where you apply `LIMIT`, and (optionally) `OFFSET` and `ORDER BY`. So:

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (<magic happens here>) alias ON true
```

A plain `JOIN` without `LATERAL` wouldn't work.
`LEFT JOIN` to report the tag even if no articles were found. Else switch to `CROSS JOIN`.

While being at it, and while you report all keys with their original column names, you can use shorter syntax, too:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.description, atu.articles
FROM   tags t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(article) AS articles
   FROM  (
      SELECT a.id, a.fore_image, a.title, a.slug, a.content
           , a.is_published, a.created_at, a.updated_at
           ,(SELECT author
             FROM  (
                SELECT u.id, u.email, u.first_name, u.last_name
                     , u.is_active, u.is_staff, u.is_superuser
                FROM   users u
                WHERE  u.id = a.user_id
                ) author
            )
      FROM   articles_tags a_t
      JOIN   articles      a ON a.id = a_t.article_id
      WHERE  a_t.tag_id = t.id
      ORDER  BY a.slug, a.id  -- or whatever
      OFFSET 0
      LIMIT  123
      ) article
   ) atu ON true
WHERE  t.Id = 3;
```

To report *all* columns of the tables `articles` and `users`, simplify further:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.description, atu.articles
FROM   tags t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(article) AS articles
   FROM  (
      SELECT a.*, (SELECT author FROM users AS author WHERE author.id = a.user_id)
      FROM   articles_tags a_t
      JOIN   articles      a ON a.id = a_t.article_id
      WHERE  a_t.tag_id = t.id
      ORDER  BY a.slug, a.id  -- or whatever
      OFFSET 0
      LIMIT  123
      ) article
   ) atu ON true
WHERE  t.Id = 3;
```

See:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26486910/939860)
- [Using row_to_json() with nested joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13227451/939860)
- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

Comment: This works too. Thank you. Performance-wise, how efficient is this query?

Comment: @Sirjon: What do you mean "too"? The currently accepted answer cannot work at all for your purpose. It picks rows uncorrelated to the main filter `WHERE t.Id = 3`. (Well, if *3* happens to be your smallest `t.id`, that query may *appear* to work for this particular filter.) This query is as efficient as it gets. The right indexes on joining and filtering columns are key to performance, plus a multicolumn index that supports your undisclosed `ORDER BY` in table `articles`.

Comment: if I want to get an estimate of total row count before limit/offset, how can I combine that with this query? I have seen [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28888696/11909958) but that's too costly and I don't want exact total count.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to limit the number of `articles`, so you could put that `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` into a subquery on that table. Instead of

```
JOIN articles AS a
```

write

```
JOIN (SELECT id, fore_image, title, slug, content,
             is_published, created_at, updated_at, user_id
      FROM articles
      ORDER BY id /* or something else */
      OFFSET 0 LIMIT 50) AS a
```

Comment: @Sirjon: This can't be the solution to your question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter It's not.